# What's the right way to implement ValueTaskSource.SetCompleted

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, valuetask, ivaluetasksource

So we have this class implementing `IValueTaskSource` This code cannot be written as async-await because there's nothing to await on. We send a message to another running thread and get back a ValueTask that can be awaited by the caller to get the notification that the other thread has finished processing the message. However the other thread is pre-existing and already doing work. It receives the message by a completely other way; processes the message, then needs to tell the threadpool-origin thread that it finished. Thus; `IValueTaskSource`

There is no stock `ValueTaskSource` (not getting into whether or not there should be; however in this case a stock version would be of questionable utility). What we actully have looks very much like this:

```
class Message : IValueTaskSource {
    public ValueTask Send()
    {
        /* how the message is sent is irrelevant */
        return new ValueTask(this, 0);
    }

    private Action<object> continuation;
    private object continuationState;

    void IValueTaskSource.OnCompleted(Action<object> continuation, object state, short _, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags __)
    {
         lock(this) {
              if (GetStatus(_) == ValueTaskSourceStatus.Pending)
              {
                  this.continuation = continuation;
                  this.continuationState = state;
                  return;
              }
              continuation(continuationState); /* Suspect */
         }
    }

    public void SetCompleted()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
             /* set state completed omitted for brevity */
             continuation?.Invoke(continuationState); /* Suspect */             
        }
    }
}
```

I think I'm doing this wrong. Imagine a large chain of these; it seems like it would build up too much stack. In particular, the lines marked `/* Suspect */` are exactly that; and `ValueTaskSourceOnCompletionFlags` is unused. Although it does have the nicety in that an exception thrown by `continuation` always goes somewhere; assuming that's even a real issue.

Right now, the code works because there are only three of them and the continuations that use them are very much thread agnostic which thread they are on.

Comment: Why not use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`?

Comment: @StephenCleary: An interesting question. I can't not use `ValueTask` but it's possible to wrap a `Task` into a `ValueTask`. It wastes a bunch of allocations but it's not terrible. It might just be kicking the can down the road though. Eventually I want to be able to use `IValueTaskSource` pooling for another thing.

Comment: Currently, the only people using manual `ValueTask` pooling (e.g., using [`ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.manualresetvaluetasksourcecore-1?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058)) are the ones willing to investigate the BCL source code using it.

Comment: @StephenCleary: I see. There's actually another example at https://github.com/kkokosa/PooledValueTaskSource/blob/master/src/PooledValueTaskSource/FileReadingPooledValueTaskSource.cs that I've almost untangled although I'm going what *is* half this stuff still.

Comment: FYI, holding a lock while invoking a callback is a very bad idea that may lead to difficult to diagnose deadlocks.  `lock(this)` is also an anti-pattern, because external code can try to lock on the same object.  It's recommended to create a private `object` instance just to use for locking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the link to [ManualResetValueTaskSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.manualresetvaluetasksourcecore-1?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) provided by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) and the corresponding [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Sources/ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore.cs) I was able to produce an answer.

`ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>` provides a complete implementation of `IValueTaskSource<T>` and `IValueTaskSource<T>`. This is currently a case of there's no `void` implementation so create a void implementation with a dummy type. There's some generalized debate on whether `bool` or `object` is the best dummy type but I think it doesn't really matter because member padding of `T` will force alignment anyway.

So the answer is to forward all the methods.

```
    public ValueTask Send()
    {
        /* how the message is sent is irrelevant */
        return CraeteValueTask();
    }

    private ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<object> taskSource;

    private ValueTask CreateValueTask() => new ValueTask(this, taskSource.Version);
    public ValueTaskSourceStatus GetStatus(short version) => taskSource.GetStatus(version);
    public void OnCompleted(Action<object> continuation, object state, short version, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags) => taskSource.OnCompleted(continuation, state, version, flags);
    public void SetCompleted() => taskSource.SetResult(null);
```

In this case each message is in its own object so there's no pooling. Doesn't matter. Calling the existing implementation is so much easier than trying to write down the smallest correct implementation that it's still the better way.

I'm pretty sure if I were pooling value task sources the correct way would be to call `Reset()` inside `CreateValueTask()`.

Comment: Nice. But if you are not going to pool your `IValueTaskSource<T>` implementation, then you have effectively created a more obscure version of the `TaskCompletionSource`. The whole point of implementing the `IValueTaskSource<T>` interface is to reuse the same objects for multiple operations.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I thought it was rather so I could pass it to `ValueTask` directly rather than creating a `Task` and wasting two allocations. The only thing that gets allocated here is caller's state machine, which is unavoidable. `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>` is a struct not a class. There isn't a missing initializer in this code.

Comment: The `TaskCompletionSource` allocates indeed two objects, itself and the underlying `Task`. But I highly doubt that your implementation doesn't allocate anything. Could you include the definition of the type that contains this code?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: `class Message : IValueTaskSource` is in the question; allocating the thing itself is an unavoidable allocation. And even my bad implementation in the question doesn't allocate anything else.

Comment: Oh, I see. You have already an object, and you can afford to double it as the mechanism for the asynchronous teleportation. It's not a public class, so you don't mind loading it with all kinds of weird interfaces. In that case the alternative could be to make it awaitable, by having a `GetAwaiter` method that returns itself, and implementing the `INotifyCompletion` interface. If you are interested I could post an answer showing how to do it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: `INotifyCompletion` is awkward for me for reasons not visible in this code fragment. However you could write an answer using anyway. It may well be usable for the next person. Caller is using `await` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the [`INotifyCompletion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.inotifycompletion) interface to get the notification, instead of the heavier `IValueTaskSource`+`ValueTask` mechanism. The `Message` class is amended with just one additional instance field, an `Action`, and it has become awaitable by exposing a `GetAwaiter` method. Each `Message` instance is intended to be awaited only once.

```
public class Message : INotifyCompletion
{
    private static readonly Action _completedSentinel = new(() => { });
    private Action _continuation;

    public Message GetAwaiter() { return this; }
    public bool IsCompleted
        => ReferenceEquals(Volatile.Read(ref _continuation), _completedSentinel);
    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        Action original = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _continuation,
            continuation, null);
        if (original is null) return; // Normal case
        if (ReferenceEquals(original, _completedSentinel))
            continuation(); // Rare case
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Double await");
    }
    public void GetResult() { }

    public void SetCompleted()
    {
        Action continuation = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _continuation,
            _completedSentinel);
        if (continuation is null) return;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => ((Action)state).Invoke(), continuation);
    }
}
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AzmTlW).

The static `_completedSentinel` field is used in order to resolve a race condition that might occur, between the thread that `await`s and the thread that invokes the `SetCompleted` method. Normally the `await` will happen first, but the implementation above will not break if it happens after the `SetCompleted`, or even if the `SetCompleted` is invoked between the `IsCompleted`/`OnCompleted` calls (these are called by the async/await machinery).